# Adobe Analytics evars, props & events in App Measurement 2.0.0

Tags: adobe-analytics

i know adobe analytics/sitecatalyst for a while now (and i know all those "dont combine props and success events etc.") but i am still confused about the results i see in my reports: what are those numbers telling me ***exactly***?

background: I stumbled across the idea of "page view success events", but i am not sure if this is still state of the art.
for my example i use one prop and evar, which contain exactly the same characteristics (prop = evar).

***props + page views + visits + instances + orders***

**result:** 0 pageviews < 100 visits < 120 instances (orders not selectable)

**my interpretation:** this prop is set in an s.tl() call, so no page views are related (?). it was set 120 times in 100 sessions, so some sessions triggered the prop more than once. success metrics (purchase metrics) cannot be combined with props.

***evars + page views + visits + instances + orders***

**result:** 20 orders < 100 visits < 120 instances < 6.000 page views

**my interpretation:** the variable was set in the same s.tl() call like the prop above, thats why visits and instances are matching. after setting this variable, 20 orders were triggered. furthermore, after the s.tl() call which set the variables, the 100 sessions triggered 6.000 additional s.t() calls (?).

I guess it must depend somehow on the sequence of s.t() and s.tl() calls but i am not sure..would be very glad if someone could shed some light :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

eVars persist data, so the 6000 page views are all page views that occurred after it was defined until the eVar expired (defaults to visit).

Page views are only s.t() calls; Instances are the number of times it was defined in both s.t() and s.tl() calls.